# Scraping data with with selenium and Python

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I need to get this data only when the game is in progress, I was unable to get the blue value:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p4rn.png)

These are the elements that I can't get, because they all have the same name including those of the games not in progress:

`<span class="bet-button-price">3.1</span>
<span class="bet-button-size">3.1</span>`

I managed to get the time, and the result, this is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep



x = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='G:\Python\Driver\chromedriver')

x.get('https://www.betfair.it/exchange/plus/football/inplay')

#Wait
wait = WebDriverWait(x, 100)
#Read Minute
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'middle-label')))
#Read Result
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'home')))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'away')))
#Read Bet
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'bet-button-price')))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'bet-button-size')))


def read_score():
    partite = 0
    tempo = 0
    score1 = 0
    score2 = 0
    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0
    i = 0
    for elm in x.find_elements_by_css_selector(".middle-label,.home,.away"):

        if i==0:
            partite = partite +1
            tempo = elm.text
        elif i==1:
            score1 = elm.text
        elif i==2:
            score2 = elm.text
        if i <2:
            i=i+1
        else:
            i = 0
            x1 = x.find_elements_by_xpath('//*/div[@class=".middle-label"]/following-sibling::div[@class="bet-button-price"]')
            x2 = x.find_elements_by_xpath('//*/div[@class=".middle-label"]/following-sibling::div[@class="bet-button-size"]')
            print("Partita #" + str(partite) + " - Tempo: " + str(tempo) + " - Risultato: [" + str(score1) + " - " + str(score2) + "] - Quotes: " + str(x1) + " - " + str(x2))
            print("-----------")

            print(str(x1) + " - " + str(x2))




count = 0
while count == 0:
    #try:
        sleep(5) 
        read_score()
        sleep(10) 
        x.get('https://www.betfair.it/exchange/plus/football/inplay')
        sleep(5)
    #except Exception:
        #print("Error")
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: does it give them all to you when you use parse it using that tag? @me when you have a response

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't get them, I tried to add them in the for loop but it takes any value with that class, including those of the games not yet started

Comment: do you always want the values of the top game

Comment: or a game in a countable concurrent position

Comment: I need to get the values of all the games in progress, have this css: .middle-label

Comment: is there any identifier that says a game is not in progress?

Comment: In the blue score no

Comment: @dr0per send me the site

Comment: The site is this: [link](https://www.betfair.it/exchange/plus/football/inplay)